# Show $\cos \pi z=\prod\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1-\frac{2z}{2n-1}\right) e^{\frac{2z}{2n-1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

I have already shown $\cos \pi z=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n-1)^2}\right)$. Here is what I have after that,
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\cos(\pi z)   & = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\left(1+\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\\
     & = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\\
     & = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\prod_{-\infty}^{n=-1}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n+1)}\right)\\
     & = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\prod_{-\infty}^{n=0}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\\
     & = \prod_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)
\end{split}\end{equation*}
I'm not sure where the exponential comes from.

Comment: It turns out that the exponential factors are absolutely necessary for convergence purposes.

Comment: you cannot split $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\left(1+\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)$ into 
$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{2z}{(2m-1)}\right)$ without checking that it converges, and it doesn't,

Comment: this is why you need the $e^{\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}}$ terms : 
$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)\left(1+\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right) $ $ = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)e^{\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}}\left(1+\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)e^{-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}} =$ $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}\right)e^{\frac{2z}{(2n-1)}}\prod_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{2z}{(2m-1)}\right)e^{-\frac{2z}{(2m-1)}} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$
\begin{align}
\csc\left(z\right)-\frac{1}{z}= &\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},\, k\neq0}\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{k\pi}+\frac{1}{z-k\pi}\right) \\ = & \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},\, k\neq0}\left(\frac{1}{2k\pi}+\frac{1}{z-2k\pi}\right)-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1\right)\pi}+\frac{1}{z-\left(2k-1\right)\pi}\right)
\end{align}$$ so if we integrate we have $$
\begin{align}
\left.\log\left(\frac{\tan\left(z/2\right)}{z}\right)\right|_{0}^{2x}= & \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left.\left(\log\left(z-2k\pi\right)+\frac{z}{2k\pi}\right)\right|_{0}^{2x} \\ - & \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left.\left(\log\left(z-\left(2k-1\right)\pi\right)+\frac{z}{\left(2k-1\right)\pi}\right)\right|_{0}^{2x}
\end{align}
 $$ then $$\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x\cos\left(x\right)}=\frac{\prod_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi k}\right)\exp\left(\frac{x}{k\pi}\right)}{\prod_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2x}{\pi\left(2k-1\right)}\right)\exp\left(\frac{2x}{\pi\left(2k-1\right)}\right)}.
 $$ With the same method, from $$\cot\left(z\right)-\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},\, k\neq0}\left(\frac{1}{k\pi}+\frac{1}{z-k\pi}\right)
 $$ it is possible to prove that $$\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}=\prod_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi k}\right)\exp\left(\frac{x}{\pi k}\right)
 $$ (and we recall that the term $k=0
 $ is omitted) hence $$\cos\left(x\right)=\prod_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2x}{\pi\left(2k-1\right)}\right)\exp\left(\frac{2x}{\pi\left(2k-1\right)}\right).
 $$

Comment: and why would you assume that we know such a pole decomposition of $\csc(z)$ ?...

Comment: @user1952009 I can't predict what you know or not. The question is to prove an identity and this is a way.

Comment: this is not the question, and if you wanted to give a complete proof, you didn't since your formula for $\csc(z)$ is "magic" (at least explain why starting from $\csc(z)$ or $\cot(z)$ would be easier...)

Comment: Title: "Show $\cos(\pi z)$=...". In the question: "I'm not sure where the exponential comes from." So I think my answer shows how the exponential comes from. We always need to start from something to start a proof. I can find a reference for the two identities (with the proofs) but I wouldn't call it "magic".

Comment: I'm sorry but the exponential only comes to make the product convergent... the true product is without the exponential, by grouping the terms by two. when you change the order of summation, you have to add the exponentials to make the logarithm of the product absolutely convergent. you didn't show that, (read my comment above to see what was the answer to his question) and I'm ensure you know all the possible ways to prove the product formula for $\cos(z)$ and the series formula for $\cot(z)$ (with the residue theorem or the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem )

Comment: or even the Liouville theorem applied to $\cot(z) - \sum \ldots$

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point. I used $$\log(z-2k\pi)+\frac{z}{2k\pi}=$$ $$\log\left((z-2k\pi)\exp\left(\frac{z}{2k\pi}\right)\right)$$ and so here we have the exponential. What you said is right, it makes the product absolutely convergent but I only shows a way to see how it comes out. If there are some mistakes I will delete the answer without problems :)

Comment: see my comments just below the OP question

Comment: and note that exactly in the same way : $\displaystyle \cot\left(z\right)-\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},\, k\neq0}\left(\frac{1}{k\pi}+\frac{1}{z-k\pi}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{z-k\pi} + \frac{1}{z+k\pi}\right)$

Comment: and to prove that, you can prove first that $\cot(z) - \frac{1}{z} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{z-k\pi} + \frac{1}{z+k\pi}\right)$ is an entire function (it has no pole and it is everywhere complex differentiable), and that it is bounded when $|z| \to \infty$, hence it is constant by the [Liouville theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: I have to agree with user1952009 in this case. It is circular to use that pole decomposition without first deriving it which is essentially just as hard as what I was trying to show. The "correct" answer is that the exponentials make the product absolutely convergent.